# Screen Capture using Java Robot saves black image instead of original image

Tags: java, selenium, automation, awtrobot

I'm using Java ROBOT to make a screen capture. But it is saving the image as a plain black screen. I don't understand what's wrong with the code i'm using. Can anyone knows the issue i'm facing here

here is the code -

// generate the screen shot of the exception

```
     File tempFile = null;
            try {
                BufferedImage img = getScreenAsBufferedImage();
                tempFile = createTempFile();
                ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", tempFile);
                template.setScreenshot(tempFile);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // error creating screenshot
                log.error("Error creating image screenshot ", e1);
            }

private BufferedImage getScreenAsBufferedImage() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            Robot r;
            r = new Robot();
            Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());
            img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }

private static File createTempFile() {
        try {

            // create a temp file
            File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".jpg");
//            log.info("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
            return temp;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }
```

**HybridTemplate.java**

```
 public File getScreenshot() {
        return screenshot;
    }

    public void setScreenshot(File screenshot) {
        this.screenshot = screenshot;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's work fine after remove one line.. check in below commented line

```
File tempFile = null;
        try {
            BufferedImage img = getScreenAsBufferedImage();
            tempFile = createTempFile();
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", tempFile);
            //template.setScreenshot(tempFile); //problem in this line 
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // error creating screenshot
            //log.error("Error creating image screenshot ", e1);
        }
private BufferedImage getScreenAsBufferedImage() {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        Robot r;
        r = new Robot();
        Toolkit     t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());
        img = r.createScreenCapture(rect);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
}
private static File createTempFile() {
    try {
        // create a temp file
        File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".jpg");
        System.out.println(temp.getAbsolutePath());
       //log.info("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
        return temp;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: This template.setScreenshot(tempFile); refers to java file. I've added in the code above. Please check this. @Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium Robot with Chrome Driver**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
        driver.get("http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/stickiness");
//http://www.theedublogger.com/2012/11/08/how-to-add-a-link-to-a-specific-location-in-a-post-or-page/
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
        Long clent_height = (Long) jse.executeScript("return window.document.documentElement.clientHeight");

        // AWT Toolkit For Window
        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Rectangle winSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
        int taskBarHeight = screenSize.height - winSize.height;
        System.out.println("Screen : "+screenSize.height +","+screenSize.width);
        int yaxis =   (int) (screenSize.getHeight() - (taskBarHeight + clent_height.intValue()));
        Robot robot = new Robot();
            int x = 0, y = yaxis;     
            int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth(), height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
         Rectangle area = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height-taskBarHeight-y);
         BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
         ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("D:\\Yash\\Robot.jpg"));

         driver.quit();

    }
```